# What's the difference between "Both at" and Both for"?

Tags: word-choice, prepositions

I was wondering if there's a difference between "Both at" and "Both for" in standard English as used when quoting the prices for two different items. 
There was a misunderstanding when I hurriedly replied "Both at $100" meaning to say they each cost $100 but was misunderstood as "Both for $100", the two together cost $100.
Am I right in making such distinctions, or do they not exist at all?

Comment: I don't think there's a distinction between the two. To clarify you would have to say $100 each.

Comment: If there was a misunderstanding, there is a need for clarification. Deleted forms are often notoriously ambiguous. I'd take "Both at $100" to probably be a deleted form of "Both are priced at $100" and "Both for $100" to probably be a deleted form of "You may buy (etc) the pair for $100 in total", but note the caveat 'probably'.

Comment: Thank you so much for your comments, they're much appreciated! I

Comment: Thank you so much for your comments, they're much appreciated! I made the distinction because when we write "4x Item A @ $100", it would/should(?) be understood as "4 items at(@) $100 each", so a total of $400. Edwin, I think your explanation is quite spot on (sic). For is like saying "For a total of".